# i'm getting an error while using findViewById()

Tags: android, findviewbyid

i want to use the method (`findViewById`) but i get an error which i cant solve.
the error is "Type Parameter T has incompatible upperbounds: View and RatingBar".

For fixing this i tried closing the activity and opening another one but it didn't work.

```
public class RatingBar extends AppCompatActivity {

    RatingBar got , bd;
    TextView gottxt , bdtxt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rating_bar);

        init()
    }

    private void init(){
        got = findViewById(R.id.gotrate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you send part of the code?

Comment: Please post your code to investigate

Comment: Why are you using RatingBar as your activity name? It's the reserved name. Change name of your Activity and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is Problem :** ` got = findViewById(R.id.gotrate); && Also Change Name of Activity becauase it is reserved Word

`
**it will like this :**

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   RatingBar got , bd;
   TextView gottxt , bdtxt;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_rating_bar);
  init()
}
private void init(){
     got = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.gotrate); 
}
```

Comment: you don't really need to parse it to RatingBar

Answer (score 3):

you are using RatingBar as your activity name. It's the built-in class in Android. Change name of your Activity and try again

Comment: @iliya You're welcome. please mark it as Accept Answer

Comment: Not really true to say that it's a "reserved name", it's just a regular class and if you'd want your `Activity` to be called `RatingBar` (not saying you should) then it's just a matter of handling the imports correctly. Actual "reserved names" (or  `keywords`) in Java are for example `break`, `default`, `continue` etc.

Comment: it's a reserved name of a class in Android, I hope

Comment: It's definitely not

Comment: It isn't a builtin class in Android?

Comment: It's a built in class but if you'd like to create another class with the same name, there's nothing stopping you, it's just another package and import.

Comment: Right. I've updated my answer. But it's a bad practice to use the same name for built-in classes as User-defined class names. As if you'll do so and you import the class accidentally, you'll not get the error  easily as the person who posted the question was confused,

Answer (score 0):

declare RatingBar as final (eg. `Final RatingBar` or `Final TextView`)and see if it can solve the issue